# MVC 5.2 Cookie Sign In OWIN and Injecting Authenticated User Information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, session-cookies, owin

I am in a bit of a pickle with my MVC Application due to the way I have coded up (currently) the implementations of my application services and the way they are configured for dependency injection.

I'm looking to separate the layers of the application by following SOLID principles.

The problem is that in some of these services, the constructor requires an instance of IUserContext.  IUserContext contains the various information about the logged in user and will be passed around a few different layers.

```
public class ProjectDataLoader : DataLoaderBase, IProjectDataLoader
{
    public ProjectDataLoader(IMyDbContext dbContext, IUserContext userContext)
        : base (dbContext, userContext)
    {
    }
    ...

    public IEnumerable<ProjectViewModel> Find(string filter = "")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And an implementation of IUserContext:

```
public class AspNetUserContext : IUserContext
{
    ...
}
```

I could pass IUserContext on every method call but I feel it belongs in the constructor.  But that is not the question here.

When I sign in from the login page via AccountController, MyAppSignInManager.SignInOrTwoFactor gets called via the OWIN pipeline.  At this point I was creating a new instance of AspNetUserContext in the session:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UserContext"] = aspNetUserContext;
```

Now I have custom SignInManager implementation:

```
public class MyAppSignInManager : SignInManager<MyAppUser, string>
{
    ...
}
```

I have a custom IUserStore implementation:

```
public class MyAppUserStore : IUserPasswordStore<MyAppUser>,
    IUserStore<MyAppUser>
{
    ...
}
```

All of the above have been hooked up for Dependency Injection with Simple Injector my choice of container.

```
public static class DependencyConfig
{
    public static Container Initialize(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        Container container = GetInitializeContainer(app);
        container.Verify();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
            new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

        return container;
    }

    private static Container GetInitializeContainer(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var container = new Container();

        RegisterCommon(container);
        RegisterRepositories(container);
        RegisterDataLoaders(container);
        RegisterAppServices(container);
        RegisterMvc(app, container);

        return container;
    }

    private static void RegisterCommon(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IUserContext>(() =>
        {
            IUserContext context = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
                context = new AspNetUserContext(Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty);
            else
                context = (IUserContext)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserContext"];

            return context;

        }, Lifestyle.Transient);
    }

    private static void RegisterRepositories(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserRepository>(() =>
            new UserRepository(container.GetInstance<IMyApp4Context>()));

        container.Register<IMyApp4Context>(() => new MyApp4Context(),
            Lifestyle.Transient);
    }

    private static void RegisterDataLoaders(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IProjectDataLoader, ProjectDataLoader>();
        container.Register<ContractDataLoader>();
        container.Register<DrawingDataLoader>();
        container.Register<WeldDataLoader>();
    }

    private static void RegisterAppServices(Container container)
    {
    }

    private static void RegisterMvc(IAppBuilder app, Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterSingle(app);
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MyAppUserManager>();
        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<SignInManager<MyAppUser, string>,
            MyAppAppSignInManager>();

        container.RegisterPerWebRequest(() =>
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current != null && 
                HttpContext.Current.Items["owin.Environment"] == null && 
                container.IsVerifying())
            {
                return new OwinContext().Authentication;
            }
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        });

        container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUserStore<MyAppUser>>(() =>
            new MyAppUserStore(container.GetInstance<IUserRepository>()));

        app.UseOwinContextInjector(container);

        container.RegisterMvcControllers(
                Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    }

    private static void InitializeUserManager(MyAppUserManager manager, IAppBuilder app)
    {
        manager.UserValidator =
         new UserValidator<MyAppUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator()
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider =
             app.GetDataProtectionProvider();

        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
             new DataProtectorTokenProvider<MyAppUser>(
              dataProtectionProvider.Create(purposes: new string[] { "ASP.NET Identity" }));
        }
    }

}
```

And also:

```
public partial class Startup
{   
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, Container container)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => container.GetInstance<MyAppUserManager>());

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString(value: "/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<MyAppUserManager, MyAppUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value: 30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) =>
                    {
                        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager);
                    })
            }
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
    }
}
```

Then these are to be used in the controllers:

```
public class ProjectController : MyBaseContextController
{
    public ProjectController(IProjectDataLoader loader)
        : base(context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My initial question was going to be how can I get MyAppUser after the cookie authentication has taken place.  Maybe asking this is still valid.

The better question is to ask what I am trying to accomplish. Essentially what I want is to inject IUserContext into my services.  This needs to be injected into the constructor of the various service implementations registered in my DI container.  However, this instance won't be available until a user has logged in/authenticated.

**NOTE:** All of the user information is stored in SQL and I use Entity Framework to access all of this.

So given that once a user has authenticated by logging in via the login page via the MyAppSignInManager.SignInOrTwoFactor method and also by a cookie, how can I make my AspNetUserContext (IUserContext) instance available to my DI container?

**NOTE**: I just want to get the user information from the database once - rather that every call to the controllers where it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I just want to get the user information from the database once."

You should consider storing your required user data in claims.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString(value: "/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<MyAppUserManager, MyAppUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value: 30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) =>
            {
                return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager);
            })
    }
})
```

The `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method adds the core identity claims but you can override this and store custom claims that your services need. Then instead of passing in a IUserContext to your service you could pass in an `IClaimsIdentity`.

This would mean you don't have to query the database all the time to get the data you need. The claims would be automatically updated after the 30 minute interval as specified in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: at what point does this get called?  When I am authenticating through a cookie regenerateIdentity does not get called.  Do I need to do any additional ground work?

Comment: Think I get ya.  With no extra work the user Guid is already stored in a claim by the owin middleware.  Then I can add all of the other user data into the claims for the identity.